# Tuple == Confusion

Tags: c#, .net, tuples, equality

Suppose I define two tuples:

```
Tuple<float, float, float, float> tuple1 = new Tuple<float, float, float, float>(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f);
Tuple<float, float, float, float> tuple2 = new Tuple<float, float, float, float>(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f);
```

If I try to compare the tuples, I get different results

```
bool result1 = (tuple1 == tuple2);    // FALSE
bool result2 = tuple1.Equals(tuple2); // TRUE
```

I would expect for both calls to return true.  What exactly is `==` comparing?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For Tuple, the == is comparing the object references because it does not *overload* the `==` operator. Since the objects are equivalent, but not the same specific instance, `Equals()` returns `true` and `==` returns `false`.

Many types do not overload `==`, some prefer to keep a distinction between `Equals()` for equivalence and `==` for reference equality.

In addition, relying on `==` for equivalence can lead to some weirdness:

```
public bool AreSame<T>(T first, T second) where T : class
{
    return first == second;
}
```

The code above will always check for reference equality because an unconstrained generic is considered an `object` at compile time, thus if the method isn't virtual, you will get object's version (even if the type, such as `string` overloads `==`).

Thus this usage of the above code:

```
var x = "Hello";
var y = "H";

// doing concat to avoid string interring
AreSame(x, y+"ello");
```

Yes, the strings are equivalent, yes `T` is `string`, but the `==` is bound to object's `==` since the generic is unconstrained, thus this will return `false` even though the same code with explicit `string` parameters would return `true`.

Comment: Thanks I had assumed that `==` and `Equals` were essentially the same.  My confusion comes from MSDN's overloading guidelines, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx, where the `==` checks for more than just reference equality.

Comment: The best rule-of-thumb is to check the documentation for the class to see if they implement operator==, and even then, I prefer to use `Equals()` for my equivalence checks because then it's pretty obvious you're looking for an equivalence check.  But that's me.

Comment: AFAICT, AreSame won't even compile.  I get the following error from the compiler: "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'"

Comment: Sorry, you have to say where T : class, because class's == and struct's == are two different birds...

Comment: Designing a type where == and .Equals are semantically different is just evil. Shaking my head in disbelief.

Answer (score 10):

`==` is comparing object references.  The `Tuple` class does not overload the `==` operator, so you need to use `.Equals`.

Comment: Is it not best practice to override the == operator?  I assumed all .NET classes overrode the == operator.

Comment: Since `Tuple` is immutable, it seems a reasonable argument could be made that this class would be a good candidate to overload the operator.  However, in my experience, the only sort of class I ever expect this overload is in `string` or other quasi-primitive types such as `DateTime`, `TimeSpan`, etc.

Answer (score 9):

`==` for Tuple will only see the references and hence you will see that it is false.

PS: Recommended way is to do something like:

```
var tuple1 = Tuple.Create(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f)
```

Comment: Thank goodness n +1 for that `.0f`, without it the compiler had been screaming for `double to float conversion` error...

Comment: And once you add the f, you can remove the `.0`, i.e. `1f`, `2f`, etc.